# Function returning null in Godot GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm currently developing a inventory system and I'm trying to make a check if the item can go on the inventory or hotbar before the player can pick it using Booleans. the only problem is the function that checks if the item can stack or take a slot always returns null. Would appreciate any insight on this!

the item script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const ACCELERATION = 600
const MAX_SPEED = 600
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var itemName
var itemQuantity = 1
var player = null
var beingPickedUp = false
var distanceToDestroyItem = 10
var destroyItemCounter = true

func initialize(name, quantity):
    itemName = String(name)
    itemQuantity = quantity
    $Sprite.texture = load("res://Inventory/Items/ItemIcons/" + itemName + ".png")

func _physics_process(delta):
    if beingPickedUp == false:
            velocity = velocity.move_toward(Vector2.ZERO, ACCELERATION * delta)
    else:
        var distance = global_position.distance_to(player.global_position)
        destroyItemCounter = PlayerInventory.checkToAddItem(itemName, itemQuantity)
        if destroyItemCounter == true:
            var direction = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
            velocity = velocity.move_toward(direction * MAX_SPEED, ACCELERATION * delta)
            velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
            distance = global_position.distance_to(player.global_position)
            if distance < distanceToDestroyItem:
                PlayerInventory.addItem(itemName, itemQuantity)
                queue_free()
        else:
            beingPickedUp = false
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

func ItemPickUp(body):
    player = body
    beingPickedUp = true
```

the function it calls:

```
func checkToAddItem(itemName, itemQuantity, slotType = inventory): 
    for item in slotType:
        if slotType[item][0] == itemName:
            var stackSize = int(JsonData.itemData[itemName]["StackSize"])
            var ableToStack = stackSize - slotType[item][1]
            if ableToStack >= itemQuantity:
                return true
            else:
                itemQuantity = itemQuantity - ableToStack
    if slotType == inventory:
        for i in range(INVENTORY_SLOTS):
            if inventory.has(i) == false:
                return true
            if i == INVENTORY_SLOTS - 1:
                checkToAddItem(itemName, itemQuantity, hotbar)
    else:
        for o in range(HOTBAR_SLOTS):
            if hotbar.has(o) == false:
                return true
            if o == HOTBAR_SLOTS - 1:
                return false
```

Comment: None of your `else` branches return anything. If any of the `if` statements are false, your function won't return anything, and the "default" return value is `null` in Godot

Comment: you are not using ```return``` in ```else```s. if your ```if```s are false, none of your ```return```s will execute

Comment: Thank you so much, You guys nailed it! I'll add this to my notes XD

Comment: Also, at the end of the function you could add a `return false` line so rather than null, it will always return false if no conditions match.